# Как вытащить определённое слово регулярными выражениями?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка:

```
{"username":"tanyawithlove","is_unpublished":false,"requested_by_viewer":false,"followed_by_viewer":false
```

Как из неё вытащить "tanyawithlove"? Именно регулярным выражением, а не веб-парсером.

Comment: Парсить JSON нужно парсером JSON.

Comment: Говорю регулярное выражение нужно, а не парсер)

Comment: `username":"(.*?)"`, хотя json парсер выглядит лучше

Comment: указанная Вами строка очень сильно напоминает `json`, который как Вам заметил @VladD проще/правильней получить при помощи *парсинга* `json`, который к слову к веб-парсингу никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: Регулярными выражениями JSON не парсится. Вы не должны пытаться делать это регулярками.

Comment: Подумайте, что произойдёт если, например, атрибут `username` появится во вложенном атрибуте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string source = @"{""username"":""tanyawithlove"",""is_unpublished"":false,""requested_by_viewer"":false,""followed_by_viewer"":false";
var matches = Regex.Match(source, @"""username"":""(\w+?)""");
Console.WriteLine(matches.Groups[1].ToString());
```

Хотя, как @VladD правильно заметил, такие вещи делаются специальными парсерами, а не регулярками.

Comment: Благодарю, работает идеально)

Comment: Последний вопрос, как получить значение count? {"tag":{"media":{"count":15210245,"page_info"

Comment: @inkorpus, точно так же, только регулярка будет такой: `@"""count"":(\d+?),"`

Comment: почему-то выводит просто "1"

Comment: есть ещё варианты?

Comment: @inkorpus, всё правильно должно выводить. Запятую в конце не забыли?

Comment: Почему JavaScriptSerializer неподходит? NET2.0 её тянет. Если не указывать класс - вернёт key-value ответ.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Вы у меня спрашиваете? Вы лучше автора вопроса спросите

Comment: Например потому, что поле count есть у другого подобъекта? Я ж писал в начале — регулярками не получится.

Comment: да получилось всё, просто "?" надо было убрать, вот так: @"""count"":(\d+),"